# Jquery Full Calendar prevent clickable for some particular events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the Jquery Full Calendar Event everything is working fine.Here when ever the events load if we click the Jquery dialog will appear for each and every event.Now for some particular event it should avoid that event clickable just to display only i have tried the following things..

The Script is:

```
 var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        eventClick: updateEvent,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: selectDate,
        editable: false,
        events: "JsonResponse.ashx",
        eventDrop: eventDropped,
        eventResize: eventResized,
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            //alert(event.title);
            element.qtip({
                content: event.activity,
                position: { corner: { tooltip: 'bottomLeft', target: 'topRight'} },
                style: {
                    border: {
                        width: 1,
                        radius: 3,
                        color: '#2779AA'

                    },
                    padding: 10,
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    tip: true, // Give it a speech bubble tip with automatic corner detection
                    name: 'cream' // Style it according to the preset 'cream' style
                }

            });
        }


    });

});
```

This is .ashx file method where each and every event loads.

```
  private String convertCalendarEventIntoString(CalendarEvent cevent)
    {
        String allDay = "true";
         string editable =""

        if(cevent.Holiday == "Y")
         {
            editable = "false";
         }
          else
         {
             editable = "true"
         }


        if (ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.start).ToString().Equals(ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.end).ToString()))
        {

            if (cevent.start.Hour == 0 && cevent.start.Minute == 0 && cevent.start.Second == 0)
            {
                allDay = "true";
            }
            else
            {
                allDay = "false";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (cevent.start.Hour == 0 && cevent.start.Minute == 0 && cevent.start.Second == 0
                && cevent.end.Hour == 0 && cevent.end.Minute == 0 && cevent.end.Second == 0)
            {
                allDay = "true";
            }
            else
            {
                allDay = "false";
            }
        }
        return "{" +
                  "id: '" + cevent.id + "'," +
                  "title: '" + cevent.projectname.Replace("'", "|") + "/" + cevent.activity.Replace("'", "|") + "'," +
                  "start:  " + ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.start).ToString() + "," +
                  "end: " + ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.end).ToString() + "," +
                  "allDay:" + allDay + "," +
                  "projectnumber: '" + cevent.projectnumber + "'" + "," +
                  "projectname: '" + cevent.projectname.Replace("'", "|") + "'" + "," +
                  "projectdescription: '" + cevent.projectdescription.Replace("'", "") + "'" + "," +
                  "activity: '" + cevent.activity.Replace("'", "|") + "'" + "," +
                  "Regular: '" + cevent.Regular + "'" + "," +
                  "OverTime: '" + cevent.OverTime + "'" + "," +
                  "RegularDisplay: '" + cevent.RegularDisplay + "'" + "," +
                  "OvertimeDisplay: '" + cevent.OvertimeDisplay + "'" + "," +
                  "Remark1: '" + cevent.Remark1 + "'" + "," +
                  "Remark2: '" + cevent.Remark2 + "'" + "," +
                  "Remark3: '" + cevent.Remark3 + "'" + "," +
                  "className: '" + cevent.colorclassname + "'" + "," +
                  "Duration: '" + cevent.Duration + "'" + "," +
                  "Customername: '" + cevent.Customername + "'" + "," +
                  "Status:'" + cevent.Status + "'" + "," +
                  "editable: " + editable +
                   //"backgroundColor:" + backgroundColor + "," +


               "},";
    }
```

The above code when event is in the holiday it should that prevent the cickable.....for that particular event...This code is not working

Comment: can u make a fiddle to better understand?

Comment: i do no how do it fiddle but my issue is for some events i should not be editable how to do it in the juery full calendar

Comment: Well its hard to tell.. but u can try return false on those events (as per ur cond.).

Comment: i tried you can seen my code it is not working

Comment: rather then return json data editable false why not return error from the server data and handle eventSources .. url: '/.ashx ',
            type: 'POST', error : " //do nothing or hanlde.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this ..

```
events: "JsonResponse.ashx",
```

with:

```
 eventSources: [

                 {
                     url: 'JsonResponse.ashx',
                     type: 'GET',
                     data: {},
                     error: function () {
                        //error do nothing.
                     }
                success: function (response) {
                    return response;
                       }
                 }
    ],
```

Other way to do this ..  //handle the error case as per ur need.

```
   var events = {
   url: 'JsonResponse.ashx',
   type: 'GET',
   data: {  },
    success: function (response) {
     return response;
 }
 };

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: events
});
```

And return false/error at convertCalendarEventIntoString(CalendarEvent cevent) method .. so that event will be not register. 
Need to handle the response in success.

I am not expert in ashx but i think u need to do something like that .. 
if error

```
       context.Response.setStatus(400);
```

else

```
         context.Response.Write(jsondatastring);
```

Comment: If i do like this what will it happen to other events

Comment: @WebDeveloper I updated the ans .. u need to return the response if its success. and also at JsonResponse.ashx method u need to return error in case of holiday.

Comment: Can you help me out how to handle this things in the convertCalendarEventIntoString(CalendarEvent cevent) method please

Comment: @WebDeveloper i donot much about the ashx file but u need to write ur o/p on response and if error set status 400

Answer (score 0):

just edit your eventClick function like this in fullcalender

```
 eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

   if(calEvent.editable=="true") // here you campare condition to call your "updateEvent" function 
    {
       updateEvent();

    }
    else
   {
    //show alert like not appicable

    }

}
```